# PHP script to convert multiple images into a video with imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I found this command line that uses ImageMagick to convert images into a video:

ImageMagick convert -delay 100 -quality 75 1.jpg 2.jpg movie.mpg

Is there a way to do this in php with imagick?  I am trying to find a way to do this on a website.

My google-fu has failed me and I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `convert` is the executable program you're using from the command-line, the simplest solution would be to use it from your PHP scripts ;-)

About that, you'll want to read through the [**System program execution**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) section of the manual.

You'll probably be especially interested by [`exec()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and/or [`shell_exec()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) -- and do not forget to escape your arguments, with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: I ended up with:
exec("/usr/bin/convert *jpg movie.mpg");
which creates the .mpg file but it is 0 bytes.  Perhaps my host doesn't support this function.  I could convert a jpg to gif just fine (as a test)  Thanks for your help!