# How to use ImageMagick in PHP on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, imagemagick, imagick

I am developing a Wordpress plugin which requires ImageMagick.

I was testing ImageMagick on my server with this code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: IM Trial
/

add_action('admin_menu','admin');

function admin() {
add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Watermark', 'Watermark', 'manage_options',     'handle-uploads-admin111', adminxy );
}

function adminxy() {

$input = site_url('/wp-content/plugins/New/earth_310.png');

if($input){
echo 'Input fetched';
}
else{
echo 'Probs';
}

$output = site_url('/wp-content/plugins/New/output.png');

exec("convert $input $output");
exec("/usr/bin/convert $input $output");
}
?>
```

I am running my wordpress on Hostgator and they told me that ImageMagick is installed on my server. But, the above code **does not give me any output.** Actually, it should be creating a new image file 'output.png' in /plugins/New folder. But, it is neither giving any error message nor outputting the image.

Is there something I am lacking in the code??? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use imagemagick, your example has no WordPress code that you can hook into nor any example on using php's imagemagick class.

Comment: I followed the guidelines from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121306/php-script-to-convert-multiple-images-into-a-video-with-imagick. I am using admin_menu to load my plugin. If Wordpress doesnt use Imagemagick, is der any other alternative??? I found out that there is a plugin named Imagemagick engine which uses Imagemagick, though.

Comment: Wordpress uses Image GD.

Comment: Can we create a video out of images with the help of Image GD. I opted for Imagemagick because "convert" can help in creating a video file from a sequence of images. What do you think???

Comment: No idea, you can view the functions here http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: Fine, checking out. Thanks for helping!!! Can anyone help me with this plz...

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you're using the HTTP address in the command line, which doesn't work. you must use the absolute path, so use

```
ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/New/earth_310.png';
```

Nextly, I notice that you're attempting to do a watermark. I used the GD library in my last watermarking class. Here's the code on github, maybe it will be of some use educationally, or usefully.

https://gist.github.com/2045951